# Running Vertx module on OpenShift

Tags: java, openshift, vert.x

I had a simple Vertx application with one class which I executed with

```
nohup bash -c "exec 'vertx' 'run' './src/main/java/com/mydomain/myClass.java' ...
```

in ./.openshift/action_hooks/start.
Now I have a module which can be run locally with vertx runmod, but

```
nohup bash -c "exec 'vertx' 'runmod' './src/main/java/com/mydomain/mods/user~HelloWorlldApp~0.1.27' ...
```

in my start file seems not to work. No errors, java just does not start.

How must it be run?

Answer (score 1):

You need check that you use values of **$OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP** and **$OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT**
for bind you vertx server.
For example in ssh console execute:

```
echo $OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP
echo $OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT
```

end put this values in

```
vertx.createHttpServer().listen(8080, "127.2.47.2");
```

Also typical start for vertx module in zip is

```
nohup bash -c "exec 'vertx' 'runzip' 'helloWorldApp-0.1.24-mod.zip' ...
```